# Go To File and Go To Member - de/select Current Document automatically in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to wean myself off DPack for navigation because the new Go To feature is great. However, when Current Document is selected, Go To File doesn't work.

What I'm looking for is:

- have **Go To File** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> > `f MyFile.cs`) work even with Current Document selected (or automatically deselect it)
- have **Go To Member** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> > `m MyMember`) automatically select Current Document
- or customize the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut to be less cumbersome.

Are any of those possible?

Answer (score 3):

Based on answer from **Sergey Vlasov**

1. Install [Visual Commander](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyVlasov.VisualCommander) extension to Visual Stuido
2. Open Visual Studio and go to menu `VCmd / Import...`
3. Import [Go to member and file](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/code/Go%20to%20member%20and%20file%20in%20VS%202017.vcmd) commands file 
   *Imports **GoToMember** and **GoToFile** commands*
4. Go to menu `Tools / Options`, open category `Environment / Keyboard`
5. Search for `VCmd`
6. Assign keyboard shortcut to `VCmd.Command01` (belongs to imported **GoToMember** command) 
   You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> which is also used by ReSharper, which does same thing.
7. Assign keyboard shortcut to `VCmd.Command02` (belongs to imported **GoToFile** command) 
   You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to override default GoToAll from Visual Studio
8. Profit!

Answer (score 2):

You can control the Current Document option with my Visual Commander extension. See [Go to a member in the current document](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#GoToMember) and [Go to a file in the solution](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#GoToFile) commands.